# App crashes when image from gallery gets selected

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crash, capture

The camera function in my app really driving me in nuts !!!

I have built an camera function in my app, but it crashed when I try to select the image from gallery.

```
Bitmap photo;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;
ImageView imageView;

  private void activeTakePhoto() {  // if select open camera 
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    private void activeGallery() { // if select choose from gallery
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Bitmap a = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 200);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    //photo = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(picturePath, 100, 20);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                //to generate random file name
                String fileName = "tempimg.jpg";

                try {
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    //captured image set in imageview
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

If I remove the `activeTakePhoto()` and all the line after `case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:`, the selected image can be displayed on `imageView`.

If I remove `activeGallery()`, the captured image can be display on `imageView`.

**But**, if I use the snippet code I posted here (both function), it crashed when I select an image from gallery with the `logCat` error

```
 12-10 14:49:03.507      927-927/? E/HwSystemManager﹕ :ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluged =2
    12-10 14:49:07.020  19428-19428/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/832821 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.AddMoreClaims}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3579)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3622)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436)
```

and the line is   `Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`. However, when I select capture image, the captured image still can display on `imageView`.

Comment: Are you testing on KitKat device or emulator?

Comment: @Apurva device..I don't understand why I will get a `null` in this line   `Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` as I'm using `activeGallery()`. It should ignore  `case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:` right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042511/android-camera-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-0-resul // this may help

Comment: lol, it works after removed    `Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` and `thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)`

Comment: Way to fetch image from gallery is different from os to os (blame google). You will need to write different code for different api levels, api < 11, api 11 to 18 and api >18.

Comment: @Apurva you're right. I added  `thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);` just in case the size of the captured image will bigger than 1Mb, but it doesn't make any difference altough I have removed it. The captured image still get displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing break; between switch cases block.
Once break is put, you will not get exception as fall through will not happen to case 'REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE'